# Is it possible to convert wpa_supplicant.conf to NetworkManager?

Tags: linux, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I've been using straight `wpa_supplicant` configurations for a while but now would like to switch to `NetworkManager`.  How can I get `NetworkManager` to use an existing `wpa_supplicant.conf` to generate the necessary configuration file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` ?

Only one network is configured on each device as either WPA1/2, no security or configured by WPS.  So I could probably do some sort of brute force approach to generating the necessary NetworkManager configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in c code.

The SSID and PSK are stored in the conf file.  You can parse them for the values and then call

```
nmcli dev wifi connect "SSID" password "PSK"
```